# Wortstellung bei Rheinischer Verlaufsform

Tags: word-order, gerund

Wenn man die Rheinische Verlaufsform verwendet, wird die normale Wortstellung benutzt?

> Wir sind nach Alternativen am Suchen. [2. Verb (*am/beim* + Gerundium) am Ende]

Oder kann man das *am/beim* + Gerundium anders positionieren? (Es ist kein Infinitiv, oder?)

> Wir sind am Suchen nach Alternativen.

Comment: Was es alles gibt!

Comment: So weit ich weiß, wird die Verbform sogar klein geschreiben: Ich bin am fensterputzen. Trotz der Kleinschreibung ist fensterputzen (nach Präposition) ein  Gerund mit vorangestelltem Objekt. Diese Konstruktion entspricht der englischen Konstruktion: I'm (at) cleaning windows, Nur ist die Präposition vor dem Gerund schon längst weggefallen. Heute wird die englische Verlaufsform als to be + present participle angesehen. Gerund mit Wegfall der Präposition davor wäre viel logischer und würde die Parallelität zur deutschen Konstruktion (bin am Tun) klar aufzeigen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nein. Für gewöhnlich wird das Verb ans Ende gestellt. Sieh beispielsweise diese ironische Übertreibung:

> Die Kuh am Stall am Schwanz am raus **am Ziehen**.

Auf die Frage: "Was machst du gerade?" kannst du natürlich theoretisch mit:

> Am Suchen bin ich. Dat sieht man doch.

antworten, wobei auch hier normalerweise "Ich bin am Suchen" gesagt wird.

Eine andere Wortstellung ist mir noch nicht untergekommen. "Et es wie et es!"

Comment: Aber "Wir sind nach Alternativen am Suchen" klingt für mich bizarr. Geht auch "Wir sind am nach Alternativen suchen."? Und warum nicht auch "Wir sind am Suchen nach Alternativen" mit "nach Alternativen" im Nachfeld.

Comment: @Emanuel Nun gut, sagen wir mal du sagst "Wir sind am Suchen" und dann fällt dir ein, dass du noch ergänzen willst, was du suchst, dann wäre das wohl akzeptabel. Aber da ist natürlich eine deutliche Sprech- und Denkpause drin. - Aber ich hab hier die Worte "gewöhnlich" und "normalerweise" benutzt. Du findest immer hier und da mal eine Ausnahme – in 98% der Fälle hält man sich hier aber an das Muster. Mal davon abgesehen, dass das eh alles schon verrückt klingt, "am nach Alternativen suchen" wirst du aber NICHT hören

Comment: Vielleicht sollte man ergänzen, dass die Sätze für gewöhnlich eh recht kurz sind. Das Extrembeispiel was ich gegeben haben ist nun wirklich kein Alltagsbeispiel. Oft wird gar kein Objekt verwendet. "Ich bin am putzen/kochen/aufräumen." Das Akkusativobjekt, wenn es dann erwähnt wird, wird davor gesetzt: "Ich bin den Boden am putzen", alles andere klingt wirklich abgefahren und kann sich wirklich nur aus Denkpausen oder so erklären lassen.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt ja grundsätzlich vier Möglichkeiten, und die Frage ist, welche wann geht:

> - Wir sind hier nach Alternativen am Suchen. Ich bin grad ein gutes Buch am Lesen.

Das kritschelt alles ein bisschen, weil die Sätze eigentlich zu lang sind für diese Konstruktion. Mit dem *hier* und dem *grad* finde ich aber, dass das so ok ist (klingt einfach umgangssprachlicher und mildert die Kollision des etwas höher gestochenen *Alternativen*  mit dieser doch eher umgangssprachlichen Form ab).

> - Wir sind hier am Alternativen Suchen. Ich bin am Buch Lesen.

Das geht beides. Wobei man es vielleicht mit Bindestrich schreiben sollte, um zu betonen, dass man Alternativen-Suchen und Buch-Lesen als Einheit begreift.

> - Wir sind am nach Alternativen Suchen. *Ich bin am ein gutes Buch Lesen.

Der zweite Satz geht nicht wirklich, deswegen Sternchen. Beim ersten ist die Frage, ob man nach-Alternativen-suchen als feststehenden Begriff sieht, was man vielleicht so ähnlich einstufen könnte wie ein Verb mit Präfix wie zum Beispiel *weglaufen*. Da geht nämlich auch beides (wenn auch das zweite kritschelt):

> Ich bin am Weglaufen. Ich bin weg am Laufen.

Das Problem scheint insbesondere die Kombination *am nach* und *am ein* zu sein, die es bei Fall 2 nicht gab.
Dabei kommt es aber auf Kontext an. Man könnte sich zum Beispiel vorstellen, dass der Chef einen Vortrag gehalten hat, dass das Unternehmen jetzt nach Alternativen suchen müsse und das vielleicht mehrmals betont hat. Kurz darauf könnte man sich dann unter Kollegen folgendes vorstellen:

> Was macht ihr da? - Wir sind am "nach-Alternativen-Suchen".

Die Anführungszeichen werden dabei durch eine entsprechende Betonung realisiert.

Und dann noch die dritte Variante:

> - Wir sind am Suchen nach Alternativen. *Ich bin am Lesen ein gutes Buch.

Der zweite Satz geht gar nicht, deswegen das Sternchen. Der erste Satz geht ein bisschen, wenn man wieder nach-Alternativen-suchen als einen feststehenden Begriff sieht. "Suchen nach Alternativen" ginge ja zum Beispiel auch als Titel für irgendwas (Buch, Film, Artikel), "Lesen ein gutes Buch" dahingegen nicht.

Letztlich ist es natürlich eine Frage des Sprachgefühls, aber als Rheinländer würde ich diese Reihenfolge geben. Und es führt zu Problemen, wenn der Satz an sich zu formell klingt und man dann auf Biegen und Brechen den Rheinischen Progressiv einbauen will. "Richtiger" wäre also sowas wie:

> Ich bin hier grad n gutes Buch am Lesen.